# Why does using shape(2) in fortran programs not print anything?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

Consider the following short program (Fortran95):

```
   write(*,*) shape(2)
   end
```

I tried running this with Fortran compilers (gfortran 4.8.2) and Absoft Pro Fortran 13.0.0 (mac) and I get the following result:

```
local $./a.out 

local $
```

update: Also tried gfortran 4.4.7 (linux with the same result.

Here is [what documentation of shape in gfortran says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SHAPE.html):

> ```
> RESULT = SHAPE(SOURCE [, KIND])
> ```
>
> Arguments:
>   SOURCE  Shall be an array **or scalar** of any type. If SOURCE is a pointer it must be associated and allocatable arrays must be allocated.
>
> Return value:
>   An INTEGER array of rank one with as many elements as SOURCE has dimensions. The elements of the resulting array correspond to the extend of SOURCE along the respective dimensions. **If SOURCE is a scalar, the result is the rank one array** of size zero. If KIND is absent, the return value has the default integer kind otherwise the specified kind.

*In other words, I see only a newline and not a result. Should it not tell me that the shape is 1?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correctly printing all the elements of the size-zero array `shape` returns. Printing an array of length zero results in zero numbers being printed.

It's the rank (number of dimensions) that is 1, not the length. That is, the result isn't a scalar or a matrix or some higher-order array. It's a vector. It just happens to be a vector with no elements.

Comment: And one can contrast with `shape([2])`.

Comment: no wonder it doesn't print anything. The size of the output is zero! interesting nuance in the standard!